# Using pexpect to listen on a port from a virtualbox

Tags: python, tcp, port, tcplistener, pexpect

I am trying to create a tcplistener in python (using pexpect if necessary) to listen for tcp connection from Ubuntu in virtualbox on a windows xp host. I would really appreciate it, if one of you could point me in the right direction. Thank you.

P.S: I have limited experience in the area, any help would be welcome.

Comment: It would help if you could answer the following questions: Where is your code running? Windows host or Ubuntu guest? Why do you think pexpect is necessary? Briefly stated, what is it you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Python already has a simple socket server provided in the standard library, which is aptly named [`SocketServer`](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html).  If all you want is a basic listener, check out this [example straight from the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example):

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The RequestHandler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "%s wrote:" % self.client_address[0]
        print self.data
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.request.send(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```